# System of four ODES using Eulers

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a system of four first order ODEs using Euler's method and RK4 (Runge Kutta 4th order method). 
Equations:

```
#define F1(C2)          C2 
#define F2(C1,C3)       k2/Da*C1*C3
#define F3(C4)          C4
#define F4(C1,C3)       b*k2/Db*C1*C3
```

This is the part of the code that i need help:

```
for (x=start; x<=end; x+=h){
    C1 = C1_0 + h * F1(C2);
    C2 = C2_0 + h * F2(C1,C3);
    C3 = C3_0 + h * F3(C4);
    C4 = C4_0 + h * F4(C1,C3);
    C1_0 = C1;
    C2_0 = C2;
    C3_0 = C3;
    C4_0 = C4;
}
```

When the loop reaches C4 it already has values for C1 and C3 so it calculates it from the first time instead of waiting for the next step. so the method goes all wrong. I think i will need for functions for my equations but i have never done this before so if anyone could explain me a bit further I would appreciate it.

Later on I have to solve the same system using RK4 but I guess if I understand what to do here it will be similar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using C1, C2, C3, C4 as "new" values, and C1_0, C2_0, C3_0, C4_0 as "previous iteration" values. In that case, you can just use the following:

```
for (x=start; x<=end; x+=h){
    C1_0 = C1;
    C2_0 = C2;
    C3_0 = C3;
    C4_0 = C4;
    C1 = C1_0 + h * F1(C2_0);
    C2 = C2_0 + h * F2(C1_0,C3_0);
    C3 = C3_0 + h * F3(C4_0);
    C4 = C4_0 + h * F4(C1_0,C3_0);
}
```